# Why does Spark Streaming fail with ClassCastException with repartitioned dstream when accessing offsets?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In my Spark application I create a DStream from a Kafka topic in the following way:

```
 KafkaUtils
  .createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder, (String, Array[Byte])](
    streamingContext,
    kafkaParams,
    offset.get,
    { message: MessageAndMetadata[String, Array[Byte]] => (message.key(), message.message()) }
  )
```

and later, i commit offset to Kafka topic using *asInstanceOf* function:

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
 val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges]
 // offsetRanges.length = # of Kafka partitions being consumed
 ... }
```

In this case everything is ok, but if i repartion the dstream, when i try to commit offsets I have the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges repartition

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show the code where you do the repartition?

Comment: KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder, (String, Array[Byte])] (
        streamingContext,
        kafkaParams,
        offset.get,
        { message: MessageAndMetadata[String, Array[Byte]] => (message.key(), message.message()) }
      )
      .repartition(6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you `repartition` at all_?!_ I'd say it is not allowed given the number of partitions (in KafkaRDD) is exactly the number of so-called [offset ranges](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/KafkaRDD.scala#L84-L88) (i.e. topic partitions you read records from). You'd then "damage" what Spark has calculated to be the best for parallelism and distribution.

```
  override def getPartitions: Array[Partition] = {
    offsetRanges.zipWithIndex.map { case (o, i) =>
        new KafkaRDDPartition(i, o.topic, o.partition, o.fromOffset, o.untilOffset)
    }.toArray
  }
```

Moreover, **only** `KafkaRDD` is [HasOffsetRanges](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/KafkaRDD.scala#L56):

```
private[spark] class KafkaRDD[K, V](
  ...
  ) extends RDD[ConsumerRecord[K, V]](sc, Nil) with Logging with HasOffsetRanges
```

And the official documentation in [Obtaining Offsets](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#obtaining-offsets) says so:

> Note that the typecast to HasOffsetRanges will only succeed if it is done in the first method called on the result of createDirectStream, not later down a chain of methods. Be aware that the one-to-one mapping between RDD partition and Kafka partition does not remain after any methods that shuffle or repartition, e.g. reduceByKey() or window().

With `RDD.repartition` [you simply create](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L461-L467) a `CoalescedRDD` (in so-called **RDD lineage**):

```
...
  new CoalescedRDD(
    new ShuffledRDD[Int, T, T](mapPartitionsWithIndex(distributePartition),
    new HashPartitioner(numPartitions)),
    numPartitions,
    partitionCoalescer).values
} else {
  new CoalescedRDD(this, numPartitions, partitionCoalescer)
}
```

As the RDD does not have `HasOffsetRanges` mixed-in, you get the `ClassCastException`.

If you want to increase the parallelism (and have more offset ranges in Spark's `KafkaRDD`), increase the number of partitions in the topic(s) and Spark Streaming will handle that nicely for you.

Quoting [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) (highlighting mine):

> The Spark Streaming integration for Kafka 0.10 is similar in design to the 0.8 Direct Stream approach. It provides simple parallelism, **1:1 correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions**, and access to offsets and metadata.