# Spark UnionRDD cannot be cast to HasOffsetRanges

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, rdd, classcastexception

Because I receive messages from serveral different kafka topics.So I need to use **StreamingContext.union** method to union streams.But I have some issues while trying to update kafka offsets to Zoopkeeper.

the error as follow:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges
at com.qingqing.spark.util.KafkaManager.updateZKOffsets(KafkaManager.scala:75)
at com.qingqing.spark.BinlogConsumer$$anonfun$consumeBinlog$3.apply(BinlogConsumer.scala:43)
at com.qingqing.spark.BinlogConsumer$$anonfun$consumeBinlog$3.apply(BinlogConsumer.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code as follow:
[image]

[image]

Could someone help me out in finding the issue . Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Spark Streaming fail with ClassCastException with repartitioned dstream when accessing offsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268414/why-does-spark-streaming-fail-with-classcastexception-with-repartitioned-dstream)

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how you work with the direct streaming API for Kafka and Spark Streaming. Since you're using the direct approach, there is no receiver in works here so there isn't a need for multiple streams, only a single stream which consumes all topics. You need to extract the offsets for all topics you want to consume, and then create a single instance of the `DirectKafkaInputDStream` created by `createDirectStream`. Since I don't have the code, a rough sketch would look like:

```
val offsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long] = 
  topics.map { /* create the (TopicAndPartition, Long) tuple here for each topic */ }

val kafkaInputStream = 
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, kafkaParams, offsets, (mmd) => (mmd.key, mmd.value))
```

For topics that don't have any offsets stored, just start from offset `0`.

As for the `HasOffsetRanges`, that needs to be mapped directly after creating the kafka stream transformation, only then is the underlying `RDD` actually implementing that trait. You need to the immediately `transform` over the stream:

```
val streamAfterTransform = kafkaInputStream.transform { rdd =>
  val ranges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges]
  // To stuff with ranges
}
```